# Appending text to an SPFile in document library (creating file if necessary)

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, spfile

Here is the setup.  On error i want to write (append) the error message to an SPFile in a document library.  If the file doesn't already exist i want to create it.  Searching around this is what i came up with.  However, when it attempts to create the file using SPFolder.Files.Add it throws an I/O Error exception (no inner exception/better description during debug).  If the file is already there, however, all is well and the file is updated as expected.  So first question would be what am i doing wrong.  Second would be is there a better way to do what i am doing (no doubt there is).....any help appreciated

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Exception e in cc.aggregatedException.m_InnerExceptionsList)
{
    errors.Append(e.Message + Environment.NewLine);
}

SPFile logFile = csvList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>()
                              .Where(x => x.Name.Equals(logFileName))
                              .Select(x => x.File)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

if (logFile == null)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms, uniEncoding))
         {
              sw.Write(errors.ToString());
         }

         SPFolder csvLibraryFolder = SPContext.Current.Web.Folders[libraryName];
         csvLibraryFolder.Files.Add(logFileName, ms, false);
    }
}
else
{
    byte[] fileContents = logFile.OpenBinary();
    string newContents = enc.GetString(fileContents) + 
                             Environment.NewLine + errors.ToString();
    logFile.SaveBinary(enc.GetBytes(newContents));
}
```

Comment: Can't say that I see any errors. Not that often I add files with MemoryStream, but I have always added them like this: folder.Files.Add(fileName, memoryStream.ToArray(), bool);

Comment: That fixed it....if you want add this as an answer and i'll give you the credit.  Can anyone tell me why passing a byte[] vs just the memorystream to the Add method causes an I/O Exception?  Many many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the MemoryStream as a byte[]:

```
folder.Files.Add(fileName, memoryStream.ToArray(), bool);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple approach I have used in the past with a try/catch so maybe you could revamp for your needs:

```
string myResponse = "whatever needs to be written to the file...";
        string filename = "C:\\splogs\\" + (DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_customlog.log";
        FileStream logStream = new FileStream(@filename, FileMode.Append);
        StreamWriter logfile = new StreamWriter(logStream);
        logfile.WriteLine(myResponse.ToString());
        logfile.Close();
```

Comment: A good approach to log to a file in the file system.  +1 :)  I would prefer to log to a file in the actual document library because otherwise nobody will ever pay attention to it (or more importantly have the access to pay attention to it :)